# Are there any craft beer or microbrewery in Washington and Baltimore?

Tags: breweries, local

Are there any microbreweries in Washington/Baltimore region?

What are the specialty brew from that part of the states?

Comment: Lots of them! Duclaw is a personal favorite...

Comment: pretty sure there are likely a few dozen depending on how big you want to look at, that's a fairly long list for an SE question.

Comment: Pubcrawler is where I would start: http://www.pubcrawler.com/Template/searchwc.cfm/flat/zipcode=21201/distance=25/title=Baltimore,%20Maryland#1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Raven](http://www.ravenbeer.com/)

[Dog](http://www.pubdog.net/)

[DuClaw](http://duclaw.com/)

[Monocacy](http://monocacybrewing.com/)

[And the list goes on...](http://visitmaryland.org/pages/breweries.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Heritage Brewing ([Link](http://www.heritagebrewing.com/)) in Manassas, VA.  Small brewery, great beers.  Kings Mountain is pretty good.

Lost Rhino ([Link](http://www.lostrhino.com/)) is another good one in Ashburn, VA.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Northern Virginia, there are 3 that I would highly recommend (in no particular order):
1. Port City, Alexandria, VA
2. Wild Run, Stafford, VA
3. Adventure Brewing, Stafford, VA

All three produce excellent beers.  If you're visiting the area, I would suggest that you start with Wild Run, since they are actually on a campground and next door to a hotel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of all the breweries in Maryland.

http://www.marylandbeer.org/default.asp?iId=LIILE

Flying Dog has been around for a while and has a great reputation. We get it here in California.

Answer (score 1):

Many restaurants in the area will have Flying Dog beer from Frederick, MD. Be sure to try some from Flying Dog, although it is somewhat widely distributed so that you may have some varieties where you are from. Try to find a variety that you can't get back home.